# Google App Engine Push Task always returns 405

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I have implemented a Push Task Queue at Google App Engine. This is the code how I call the Task Queue

```
 Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
 queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/tasks/myTask").param("myparam", Long.toString(myparam)).retryOptions(RetryOptions.Builder.withTaskRetryLimit(1)).method(TaskOptions.Method.POST)) ;
```

and this is the code of the Task

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp);

        String param = req.getParameter("myparam") ;

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("dummy");
        resp.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

But I can see in the logs that my Task returns the status code 405 and the Task will be executed again but in my code I set the value 200 as Response code. Any idea why my code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs state

> TaskOptions.Builder constructor has methods to add data as the payload
>   of the HTTP request, and as parameters, which are added to the URL as
>   query parameters.
>
> Params
>
> Do not specify params if you are using the POST method along with a
>   payload, or if you are using the GET method and you've included a url
>   with query parameters.

You are adding a task with a POST method.

Remove the call to `.method(TaskOptions.Method.POST)`